# Is there a way to specify the distribution of a random slope in lmer?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

I want a model with a random slope, but I want to restrict the random slope to be between 0 and 1, something like a beta distribution.
Is there a way to specify the distribution of random slope in the **lmer** models in **lme4**?

Comment: I don't think this is possible in `lme4` but maybe you can look into multilevel modelling with `rjags` it's a bit more work but you should be able to specify a different distribution on your random effects

Comment: Thanks @Niek . I heard about RStan too. Any idea which one is most preferred?

Comment: I have zero experience with `RStan` and very limited experience with `rjags` so I wouldn't know